# How to tell Swagger to replace collection type entirely with string?

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

I have problems with automatically generated model schema by Swagger. I have a collection field of type `List<String>` which I want to serialize as plain string and I have separate serializer for that. Jackson is doing its job well, but not schema generator. It resolves type of the field as object despite of explictly set attribute `dataType`:

```
public class FilialDetails {
  @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "string", example = "10000101010")
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
  // custom serializer treats collection as subset of known, pre-populated list
  // and serializes it as series of 0 and 1
  @JsonSerialize(using = ServicesSerializer.class)
  private List<String> services;
}
```

Generated properties definition (excerpt):

```
  "properties": {
    "services": {
      "type": "object",
      "example": 10000101010
    }
  }
```

I need `string` in schema definition, not `object`, how it's possible? I'm using `io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0` in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I had to specify fully qualified type name for `string`

```
  @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "java.lang.String", example = "10000101010")
  private List<String> services;
```